# Testing json data using Specs2

Tags: json, scala, lift, specs2

I added(In built.sbt) matcher-extra :-

```
 "org.specs2"              %% "specs2"            % "2.3.4"                  % "test",
"org.specs2"               % "specs2-matcher-extra_2.10" % "2.3-scalaz-7.1.0-M3",
```

the ("/" the symbols are not resolving)

My example test case for Json is looking like below:-

```
package specs.model
import org.specs2.mutable.Specification
import org.specs2.matcher.JsonMatchers

class Json extends Specification with JsonMatchers {

"Json Matcher" should {
"1st field" in {
  val json = """{"name":"sagar"}"""
  json must  /("name" -> "sagar")
}
"2nd field" in {
  val json = """{"id":1}"""
  json must  /("id" -> 1.0)
}
}
}
```

ErrorMsg:-

```
 [info] Compiling 2 Scala sources to \target\scala-   2.10\test-classes...
 [info] Json
 [info] 
 [info] Json Matcher should
 [info] + 1st field
 [info] + 2nd field
 [info] 
 [info] Total for specification Json
 [info] Finished in 76 ms
 [info] 2 examples, 0 failure, 0 error
 [trace] Stack trace suppressed: run 'last specBuilder/test:test' for the full output.
 [error] Could not run test specs.model.Json: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError:     scalaz.Scalaz$.tuple2Monoid(Lscalaz/Monoid;Lscalaz/Monoid;)Lscalaz/std/Tuple2Monoid;
 [error] Error: Total 0, Failed 0, Errors 0, Passed 0, Skipped 0
 [error] Error during tests:
 [error]    specs.model.Json
 [error] (specBuilder/test:test) sbt.TestsFailedException: Tests unsuccessful
 [error] Total time: 9 s, completed 11 Dec, 2013 5:12:39 PM
```

I am strucking here please give me the solution

Thanks,

GSY

Comment: Do you have scalaz in your sbt too? Looks like the dependency might be missing. You could try adding: [`"org.scalaz" %% "scalaz-core" % "7.0.5"`](https://github.com/scalaz/scalaz)

Comment: added but same Error is comming

Comment: I added below dependency's("/" not resolving) :-    "org.specs2"              %% "specs2"   % "2.3.4"                  % "test",
     "org.specs2"              %% "specs2-matcher-extra" % "2.3.4" % "test",
     "org.scalaz"               %% "scalaz-core" % "7.0.4" % "test",
     "org.scalaz"               %% "scalaz-concurrent" % "7.0.4" % "test",

Comment: 1. After you add a dependency you have to `reload` sbt. 2. If you're getting a resolve-dependency error please post it specifically.

Comment: I Tryed this with few Dependencies in(Another Project)  its working fine ,I will check and let we Know  where the problem in my Project.

Comment: it's been more than 10 years now but I still think it's worth pointing out that it's not testing the type like one would expect. `json must  /("id" -> "1.0")` will also match even though `1.0` is a number and not a string.

Answer (score 5):

I finally got it to work.

There are some instructions for setting up your build.sbt file here.  Scroll down to the very bottom of the page. http://etorreborre.github.io/specs2/#Downloads

**The import commands in my Application.spec file are:**

```
import org.specs2.mutable._
import org.specs2.mutable.Specification
import org.specs2.matcher.JsonMatchers
import org.specs2.runner._

class yourClass extends Specification with JsonMatchers {  }
```

**The following jar files are installed in the lib directory**

```
specs2_2.10-2.3.7-javadoc.jar   
scalaz-core_2.10-7.0.4-javadoc.jar   
scalaz-concurrent_2.10-7.0.4-javadoc.jar
```

**This is the contents of my build.sbt file.**

```
name := "playExperiments"

version := "1.0-SNAPSHOT"

libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
    "org.specs2" %% "specs2" % "2.3.7" % "test",
    jdbc,
    anorm,
    cache
)     

scalacOptions in Test ++= Seq("-Yrangepos")

resolvers ++= Seq("snapshots", "releases").map(Resolver.sonatypeRepo)

play.Project.playScalaSettings
```