# How to test my scala json after creating the implicit classes

Tags: scala, play-json

I am using specs2 and want to test my json reads that I created.

I have my case classes and implicits created like:

```
object ComputerImplicits {
   implicit val partReads = Json.reads[Part]
   implicit val computerReads = Json.reads[Computer]
}
```

I have a sample json file in my `test/resources/computer.json` folder.

I am loading the JSON file as a string like this:

```
val jsonString = Source.fromURL(getClass.getResource("/computer.json")).mkString
```

I brought the implicits in scope:

```
import ComputerImplicits._
```

Now how do I take my case classes and use the json string and attempt to parse it and match it to test if it is working correctly?

I am using **Plays json macros** https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.8.x/ScalaJsonAutomated

Comment: See [Testing json data using Specs2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20518862/testing-json-data-using-specs2)

Comment: @user I don't see where the rubber meets the road.  Where do I attempt to bind my case class to the json string to convert it? I'm lost sorry...  Do I cast it, or ?

Comment: Sorry, I have no knowledge of specs2, so I can't help you. Retagging your question might bring it to the attention of people who do, though

Comment: the testing framework is irrelevant actually, just confused how to bind the json string to my case classes.

Comment: What API are you using for your JSON serialization/deserialization?

Comment: play json using macros https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.8.x/ScalaJsonAutomated @user

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming you use Play JSON:

```
final class FooSpec extends org.specs2.mutable.Specification {
  "Json" should {
    "be ok" in {
      Json.parse(jsonString).validate[YourType] must_=== JsSuccess(expectedVal)
    }
  }
}
```

Also implicit related to a type are usually declared in its companion object (rather than in a shared object).

Comment: Is it possible to get the parsed YourType object so I can test the individual properties manually also? Instead of the entire thing at once?

Comment: Looks like it is failing b/c my JSON has ```some_property``` and my case class has ```someProperty```.

Comment: Why would you check individual property? For debug? Just print the validation result.

Comment: You could use `implicit val config = JsonConfiguration(SnakeCase)` before calling `Json.reads` (in companion object) if all fields are using snake_case naming in JSON